# Loading an apk file on an AT&T device for QA/testing when

Tags: android

I'd love to get some ideas on best practices for testing our Android software, especially for AT&T devices.  We're using a Samsung Captivate, on AT&T.  As you know, AT&T disables sideloading (no Unknowns Sources option in Settings->Applications).

We need to have our QA team load our apk file onto these devices as part of our testing and validation process.  We're willing to install the SDK if needed, and upload the apk file via USB.  We are not willing to root the phone.

Can I get any suggestions/ideas on how this can be done?

Thank you,

Tony

Answer (score 0):

Install the SDK and use `adb install`. Or, download the [Sideload Wonder Machine](http://www.androidcentral.com/sideload-android-apps-all-you-want-sideload-wonder-machine) and use it. Both use the same technique, one that AT&T cannot block (at least, they cannot block it if they want the Android Market).